# convert reference type to value type in golang

Tags: go

I want to create slice of elements of type `*Person`.

```
package main

type Person struct {
    Name string
}

func convertRefTypeToType(refPerson *Person) Person {
    // is it possible to convert *Person to Person
    return Person{}
}

func main() {
    personRef := &Person{Name: "Nick"}
    person := convertRefTypeToType(personRef)
    people := []Person{personRef} // person
}
```

But have error:

```
./refConvert.go:16: cannot use personRef (type *Person) as type Person in array element
```

Is it possible to convert element of type `*Person` to element of type `Person`?
This desire may seem weird but my target function accepts argument of type `*Person` and inside this target function I have to create slice.

### [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vQSgOsQ15A)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[]Person{}` is slice of `Person`, however, you want to have slice of pointer to `Person`.
It should be defined as `people := []*Person{personRef}`.